# Why firefox open a new window for downloading jnlp file

Tags: javascript, java, firefox, java-web-start, jnlp

I have a javascript application that runs in firefox. At some point, I have to start a java application, so I created a jnlp file for it. I have a button that execute some javascript code and then call

```
window.open('GetJnlpApplication','_blank');
```

On Chrome, IE, Edge and even Firefox on Linux, this work as excepted: the browser download the jnlp file and run javaws while user remain in the application shown in browser window.

On firefox on Windows (all versions I tried: from 45 onward) a new tab is opened, then javaws is correctly run, but the browser remain on the new blank tab. Please note that IE (and FF on Linux) quickly open a new tab, download jnlp file and close the new tab.

Question is: how do I make firefox immediately close that tab?

Final note: I use target `_blank` because otherwise firefox would trigger and WindowClosing event when calling `window.open()`, and this would logout my application.

Post scriptum: I tried without the `_blank` argument and nothing changed: firefox still open a new tab and keep it opened.

Comment: Well it is _you_ that is opening a new window ... so don’t complain when exactly that happens. If you don’t want to open a new window - then don’t use window.open, but simply assign the URL to `location.href` instead.

Comment: @CBroe I cannot assign to `location.href` since this would trigger a WindowClosing event and my application would intercept it and log me out.

Comment: Closing a newly opened window that has no content to display (because the file is downloaded) is at the discretion of the browser. So I think you’ll either have to live with this - or modify your application’s logic detecting the user leaving the app. (Not sure what exactly you’re referring to by “WindowClosing event” - something Java/Swing specific ...?)

Comment: @CBroe the WindowClosing is GWT specific, you are right. I believe it is linked to the `beforeunload` javascript event.

Comment: Maybe you can try and use an iframe instead (set to 1*1px size, maybe hidden outside view using absolute positioning) - and assign the download URL to the iframe src, hoping that does not trigger the event …